# Tracing Latvian Legion service records/internment/dp records?

Tags: germany, world-war-2, latvia

Does anybody know where I would start in tracing my fathers war record/history timeline during his time conscripted into the [Latvian Legion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latvian_Legion)?

He was born in 1926 in Riga.

I have used the usual search engines.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I am assuming that this is World War 2 service and so will add tags for that and the country of Latvia to your question.  Would you be able to edit your question to include the year of birth for your father but initially no other details that might identify him, please?  Protecting people's privacy is important to us as you will see at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/how-much-detail-should-be-included-in-questions-about-ww1-and-ww2-service-member but we also like to be as helpful as possible.

Comment: Hi He was born in 1926 in Riga if this helps, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Someone at the Institute of History in Latvia will probably know. A list of academics with relevant interests is here: http://www.lvi.lv/en/occupdept.htm, with email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](http://www.lsm.lv/lv/raksts/latvija/zinas/kara-muzeja-paliidzes-uzzinat-tuvinieku-liktenjus.a79653/) Latvian museum of war has acquired archive data on the legion from Daugavas Vanagi and has a database on legionaries. Seems like on past two years they held event in March for families interested in learning more about their ancestors. The museum has a website, I don't see any information on this there, but you probably can try to contact them: http://www.karamuzejs.lv

Answer (score 1):

You can start right here. There is an additional place to search at the Bundesarchiv Deutschland, you can google their address. In the meantime you can start at this place, but it may cost you 25 dollars for them to do the research.
I successfully got some information from them, but I encourage you to track down the Bundesarchiv under Lettische Legion/Waffen-SS.

BERLIN  Unternehmen Verwaltung.
Deutsche Dienststelle (WASt)
Die Auskunftsstelle fur
Wehrmachtsnachweise.
Eichborndamm 179,   13403 Berlin
GERMANY

Break down of above address as lines. Words are abbreviated with first character. Line 1: B-U-V .Line 2: D-D Line 3: D-A-f-W Line 4: E-179,  13403-B
Line 5: Germany

Good hunting