# Locating Latvian Legion service records?

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, russia, latvia

I am interested in looking for my grandfather Adolphs Gailitis' (b.1911) service records in the Latvian Legion in WW2. He was taken as a Russian POW but I'm not sure which year.

Comment: Hi Leon – Maybe you could start by taking a look at [Tracing Latvian Legion service records/internment/dp records?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7865/tracing-latvian-legion-service-records-internment-dp-records) although the answers there do not give much specific information. If you can add any more details about your grandfather's service (if you know any more) someone may be able to give you more specific suggestions.

Comment: I added a tag for [tag:russia] in case that country may have any POW records that include your ancestor and may aid your search.